# Django - how to make this query

Tags: django

I have the following model which is populated with something like this:

**Property**

```
concept_id   name             value

1            definition       blablabla
1            prefLabel        prefferedLabel
1            scope            Scopeee
1            NOT_NEEDED       a not needed value
2            definition       another definition
2            prefLabel        another label
2            scope            another scope
.........................
```

I want to obtain this result in query(under the form of a list, dictionary, queryset, it doesn't matter which form):

```
concept_id      definition            prefLabel         scope

1               blablabla             prefferedLabel    Scopeee
2               another definition    another label     another scope
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

**EDIT**: I am using MySQL.

My ugly solution is this one

```
for concept_id in Concept.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True):
     Property.objects.filter(concept_id=concept_id, name__in=['prefLabel', 'scope', 'definition'])
     .....
```

But is realy ugly, I want something different

**THE SOLUTIONS OF pcoronel**:

```
    table = []
    for concept in Concept.objects.all():
        row = {'code': concept.id}
        result=concept.property_set.filter(
            name__in=['prefLabel', 'scope', 'definition'],
        )
        for r in result:
            row.update({
                r.name: r.value,
            })
        table.append(row)
```

Not sure if this is the best solution

Comment: nothing...it is simply the output I want to retrieve. The `name` column might also have others values, other than `definition`, `prefLabel` and `scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Property` model has a field: `models.ForeignKey('Concept', ...)`, you can simply [follow that relationship backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
# iterate through Concepts and get desired related Properties using their name
for concept in Concept.objects.all():
    concept.property_set.filter(name__in=['prefLabel', 'scope', 'definition'])
```

Comment: yes they are connected like so. let me give it a try

Comment: great, it worked! I edited my post for everyone to see the solution. Nevertheless, I am wondering if this is the most optimized query.